# AngularJS - Efficient way of checking values inside a json element

Tags: angularjs, json, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a json object example

```
var obj = { a: "sample", b: "sample", c: "sample" };
```

and I want to check each key if they have the same values.

```
if(a === b || b === c || c === a){ 
  console.log("Error");
}
```

is there a better way of checking these values? Any ideas would  be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Object.keys and array.every and compare all values with the first one:

```js
var obj = { a: "sample", b: "sample", c: "sample" };
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var first = obj[keys[0]]
var sameValue = keys.every(key => obj[key] === first);
console.log(sameValue);
```

EDIT:

In case you want to return true if at least two properties have the same value:

```js
var obj = { a: "sample", b: "saxmple", c: "sample" };
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
var sameValue = keys.some((key, index) => keys.some((otherKey, otherIndex) => obj[key] === obj[otherKey] && index !== otherIndex));
console.log(sameValue);
```

Comment: will try this answer later and I will you give you a feedback. Thank you for answering my question. Have a good day!

Comment: the issue I found in your code is that if the value in key a and key b is the same, it will output false. Is it possible to return true if it has the same value in two or more keys?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will never print `Error`.

You are referencing values that do not exist.

Fix this with:

```
if(obj.a === obj.b || obj.b === obj.c || obj.c === obj.a){ 
  console.log("Error");
}
```

You can also do it with:

```
var firstObj = '';
var i = 0;
var areDifferent = false;
for var prop in obj {
  if (i == 0){ 
     firstObj = obj[property]
  }
  if (firstObj != obj[property]){
    areDifferent = true;
  }
  i++;
}

if (areDifferent){
 //your code here
}
```

The code above will run through all `obj` properties, to check if all of them are equal to the first one - which means, that are of them are equal.

Comment: `i` never gets set to anything beyond `0`, so this code will always pass and report that they are not different.

Comment: @GregL, code is fixed. Forgot to increment i at the end of loop.

Comment: @uksz sorry for the incorrect implementation of the conditional statement. I was in a hurry typing my question and did not noticed it. But still the idea is the same. Thanks for answering. Will be trying your answer later and I will give you a feedback. Have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

try this **_.every** from Underscore.js

**every_.every(list, [predicate], [context])**

Returns true if all of the values in the list pass the predicate truth test. Short-circuits and stops traversing the list if a false element is found.

*_.every([2, 4, 5], function(num) { return num % 2 == 0; });
=> false*

in ur case u should check value of the first element of "obj" with all next elements in "obj"